# How to modify data type of a column that is foreign key or primary key?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a three tables. One is **course**, **section** and other is **prerequisite**.

```
CREATE TABLE course(
  course_number int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  course_name varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  credit_hours int(11) NOT NULL,
  department varchar(5) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (course_number)
)

CREATE TABLE section (
  section_id int(11) NOT NULL,
  course_number` int(11) NOT NULL,
  semester varchar(6) NOT NULL,
  year year(4) NOT NULL,
  instructor varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (section_id),
  FOREIGN KEY (course_number) REFERENCES course (course_number)
) 
create table prerequisite(
    course_number int not null auto_increment,
    prerequisite int not null,
    primary key (course_number),
    foreign key (prerequisite) references course(course_number)
    );
```

I want to change datatype of my course_number in both tables, but when I run the query

```
alter table course change course_number course_number varchar(20);
```

I see the following error:

> Cannot change column 'course_number': used in a foreign key constraint 'section_fk' of table 'university.section'

What is the problem in here? What is the best solution? By saying the best solution, I mean, not loosing any data or dropping any table and creating from scratch.

Comment: Is there any particular reason that makes you want to ruin a perfectly good structure?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Drop the foreign key, change both tables and add the foreign key. It is btw good idea to name your constraints explicitly. Now you will have to look up what the constraint name is in the catalog:

```
select CONSTRAINT_NAME from information_schema.REFERENTIAL_CONSTRAINTS
where TABLE_NAME = 'prerequisite'
  and REFERENCED_TABLE_NAME = 'course'

alter table prerequisite drop constraint ...;

alter table course change course_number course_number varchar(20);
alter table prerequisite change course_number course_number varchar(20);

alter table prerequisite add constraint <name>
    foreign key (course_number)
    references course (course_number)
        <actions>;
```